# How to use Kendo UI validator to validate inputs within an AngularJS component inside of a form

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

Suppose that I have an AngularJS component that renders inputs for a user to input their first and last name like so:

```
First name: <input ng-model="ctrl.firstName" required /><br />
Last name: <input ng-model="ctrl.lastName" required />
```

Suppose that the component is called "Name Input", and I use it as part of another form like so:

```
<form kendo-validator="ctrl.validator">
    <name-input></name-input><br />
    Quest: <input ng-model="ctrl.quest" required /><br />
    Favorite Color: <input ng-model="ctrl.favoriteColor" required
</form>
```

The result is a form with four inputs: First Name, Last Name, Quest, and Favorite Color.

However, when I invoke `validator.validate`, I see that only Quest and Favorite Color get validated.  I've tried to declare a Kendo UI validator for the Name Input component, but it doesn't work.  At runtime, the validator declared inside the Name Input component is undefined.

The only solution I've come across that seems reasonable is to use `validator.validateInput` on each input, as described here: https://www.newventuresoftware.com/blog/code-bites-validate-any-dom-element-with-kendoui-validator

In this case, I think I would have to invoke `validator.validate` to validate Quest and Favorite Color, but I would have to invoke `validator.validateInput` twice for the two inputs inside the Name Input component.

This seems like it could work, but it's very un-DRY.  The problem is that if I use `validator.validateInput` in ten different forms that use this Name Input component, and then in the future, I add a "Middle Name" input to the Name Input, then I must go back and add an additional `validator.validateInput` invocation everywhere I've used the Name Input component.

What is a better way to dot his?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, giving **name** attribute to each input will do the trick.

```
First name: <input name="firstName" ng-model="ctrl.firstName" required /><br />
Last name: <input name="lastName" ng-model="ctrl.lastName" required />
```

[Working example](https://dojo.telerik.com/OgaTezeJ)

If the component is used repeatedly inside the same form, just pass the name as binding data into component.
[Working example](https://dojo.telerik.com/OlEZOhUg/2)